# UICollectionViewCell snapshot

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, snapshot

[code] 
I need to take a snapshot of a collectionview cell for the provided indexpath, i have created the below function and it always returns image as nil

Please suggest me what am doing wrong here,

```
    func screenshotForCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath!, rect: CGRect!) -> UIImage?
{
    let cellRect = rect
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cellRect!.size, false, 0.0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.render(in: context)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

[code]

Comment: Are you sure that the value of the cell is non-nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a snapshot of Collection view cell for selected indexpath. 
Try this for taking snapshot of

```
    var yourImage: UIImage?
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    yourView.drawHierarchy(in: myView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    yourImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return yourImage!
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked fine. But still one issue, I need the background color of the view. The snapshot is with white background